# How to validate JSON to ensure all fields are non-empty and age is >0?

Tags: json, spring-boot, rest, spring-kafka

Through a Rest API endpoint, I accept JSON and using a Kafka Producer, I publish the JSON to a topic. The JSON will have this format:

```json
{
  "id": "uniqueIdentifier",
  "name": "PersonName",
  "age": PersonAge
}
```

and the send message method in my Kafka Producer looks like this:

```java
public void sendMessage(Person p){

        LOGGER.info(String.format("Message sent -> %s", p.toString()));

        Message<Person> message = MessageBuilder
                .withPayload(p)
                .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.TOPIC, "jsonTopic")
                .build();

        kafkaTemplate.send(message);

    }
```

I need to check if the JSON has all the fields non-empty and if the `age > 0`.
How would I need to implement the verification before sending the message?

Comment: For the Person POJO I would suggest the member variables to have ```@NotNull``` - to ensure the value for each member variable is provided and ```@Min(1)``` to have a value more than 0. When declaring the method do as ```public void sendMessage(@Valid Person p)``` to ensure validation is done on invoking the method.

Comment: Thanks, it worked like a charm. Now, when the JSON is not valid, it sends the response "Bad Request". Any ideea on how to implement the error handleing? (Age<0 should return "Age is not valid" or smth like that, this applying to all the fields).

Answer (score 1):

- For the Person POJO I would suggest the member variables to have `@NotNull` - to ensure the value for each member variable is provided.
- Use `@Min(1)` to have a value more than 0 for age.
- When declaring the method do as `public void sendMessage(@Valid Person p)` to ensure validation is done on invoking the method.

On error handling do the following:

- Create an exception class like below:

```
public class BadRequestException extends RuntimeException {
    public BadRequestException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Above can be thrown incase any condition above is thrown. But it needs to be caught using an advice as below:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyAdvice {
@ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<String> getHttpMessageNotReadableExceptionException(HttpMessageNotReadableException exception) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(exception.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Above will give you appropriate message for the malformed payload.

Answer (score 0):

**[JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org/)** is the best for this use case. There are libraries in all languages to validate an input JSON against JSON-Schema. E.g. [Java](https://github.com/networknt/json-schema-validator), [Javascript](https://ajv.js.org/)

The schema for your requirement should look like the following:

```js
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
    "age": {
      "type": "integer",
      "minimum": 1
    }
  },
  "required": ["id", "name", "age"],
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

Here, `additionalProperties` ensures that you do not allow anything else apart from the declared properties.

These validation libraries give very detailed validation errors that make the error actionable for the sender/caller:

```
{
   "errors" : {
      "required" : "the field 'age' should be have a minimum value as 1"
    }
}
```